# How can I make emacs ignore part of the file name when deciding major mode?

Tags: major-mode

If you have a GPG-encrypted file, say `notes.org.gpg`, emacs figures out that the major mode has to be set to `org-mode`. This applies in general to any major mode out there; you do not need to modify the `auto-mode-alist` for each major mode to support that `.gpg` extension.

I would like to have my own extra extension, let's say `.~bkp~` and have emacs ignore that when determining the major mode. Currently, if I have a file named `notes.org.~bkp~`, the `org-mode` is not set automatically.

I scoured through `files.el`, `epa*.el`, googled but couldn't figure out how emacs is ignoring the `.gpg` in the file names.

What function can I probably advice or a variable can I tweak to support my custom appended extensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant entry in `auto-mode-alist` is this:

```
 ([...] ("\\.gpg\\(~\\|\\.~[0-9]+~\\)?\\'" nil epa-file) [...])
```

And here is the documentation that describes what is going on:

> `auto-mode-alist` is a variable defined in `files.el`.
>
> This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>   Alist of filename patterns vs corresponding major mode functions. Each element looks like `(REGEXP . FUNCTION)` or `(REGEXP FUNCTION NON-NIL)`. (NON-NIL stands for anything that is not nil; the value does not matter.) Visiting a file whose name matches `REGEXP` specifies `FUNCTION` as the mode function to use. `FUNCTION` will be called, unless it is `nil`.
>
> **If the element has the form `(REGEXP FUNCTION NON-NIL)`, then after
>   calling `FUNCTION` (if it's not `nil`), we delete the suffix that matched
>   `REGEXP` and search the list again for another match.**
>
> The extensions whose `FUNCTION` is `archive-mode` should also appear in `auto-coding-alist` with `no-conversion` coding system.
>
> See also `interpreter-mode-alist`, which detects executable script modes based on the interpreters they specify to run, and `magic-mode-alist`, which determines modes based on file contents.
>
> [...]

So there you go!

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.bkp\\(~[0-9_]+~\\)\\'" nil backup-file))
```

Comment: Thanks. I might be missing something here. Your explanation makes sense and I tried to implement it but it does not work: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.bkp~[0-9_]+~\\'" nil backup-file))`. It does not set the mode for `file.sv.bkp~20150619_1427~` correctly. May be a second set of eyes of the above regexp can see the problem?

Comment: Even `M-: (string-match "\\.bkp~[0-9_]+~\\'" (buffer-file-name))` (when I am in that file buffer) returns a non-nil value; but the major mode is still set to Fundamental mode. I also tried the same with a dummy `notes.org.bkp~123~` file; same thing.

Comment: Interesting.. It works with other extensions (i have a few in my auto-mode-alist) but I just tried your specific example and get the same behavior. The file also gets opened read-only, which seems odd. Must be some other handling of that extension somewhere?

Comment: @glucas I searched for `bkp` in the `C-h v` buffer for `auto-mode-alist` and the list I added is the only one in that alist.

Comment: I think the issue is that Emacs is stripping off its own backup/version info before applying the auto-mode-alist, at which point your regexp no longer matches. Specifically, `set-auto-mode` is calling `file-name-sans-versions` before looking for matches in the auto-mode-alist.

Comment: Yeah.. If I remove that last `~` from that regexp (and my dummy file filename), it works! But then, the .gpg entry also supports files ending in `~`...

Comment: Finally! Got it working.. note the extra regexp subgroup: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.bkp\\(~[0-9_]+~\\)\\'" nil backup-file))`. Not sure what significance that has though..

Comment: @PythonNut Can you update your answer to include that regexp subgrouping parentheses and the missing single quote before the closing double quotes?

Comment: @kaushalmodi sure. I'm not sure why you need the group, but I'm glad it works! Maybe someone more knowledgeable than me can comment.

Comment: The subgrouping doesn't work for me, testing with your original file name. The file name is "foo.org.bkp~1~". When Emacs calls `set-auto-mode`, it strips off the trailing `~` and then looks for a match in the `auto-mode-alist`. If I use your original regexp minus the last `~`, then things work fine.

Comment: @glucas You are right, it doesn't after I restarted emacs.. I must have added many variants of my `backup-file` regexps into my `auto-mode-alist` while testing different regexps..

Comment: Actually - what you are using is very close to what Emacs is already stripping off as version info. If I use a file name like `foo.org.~bkp~1~` then Emacs visits that in org-mode without any additional rules in the auto-mode-alist. (Take a look at `file-name-version-regexp`.)

Comment: Changed my backup file naming: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[0-9_]+\\.bkp\\'" nil backup-file))`